# Using ASWebAuthenticationSession with OAuth or any web serivce?

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, ios12

Apple document on ASWebAuthenticationSession talks that it can be used by any web services
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession

- So does it mean any web services which can drop cookie after sucessfull user authentication will work? Or does it has to be an OAuth based service?
- If yes, how authorization will work next time, does same webservice suppose to read & validate cookie to authorize user?

Comment: I don't think, it needs to be a "conforming Xxx" - it just calls out with the given URL and calls back to you with the redirect URI matching the given custom scheme. You parse the returned URI, obtain the parameters, and that's it. Every other behaviour is defined by the browser and what service you call.